# Integrate Canada Post shipping into Suitecommerce Instore

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce, netsuite-rest-api

I want to integrate Canada Post API into suitecommerce instore. I have seen a Netsuite bundle already exists. But client wants to create custom script for this integration. I have some knowledge in suitescript APIs. But I am very new to this instore application. Can anyone suggest/guide any proper document for me to get into this? or can you help me the basic steps to understand how to work on this integration.

Thanks in advance!